# How to I send keystroke to Linux process in Python by PID?

Tags: python

One simple question: I have Linux process ID, which is 3789. How can I send 'ENTER' to this process by using Python?

Comment: Is the process waiting on reading stdin? Is it connected to a terminal, a GUI?  Was it started by the Python program?

Comment: Yes, the process is waiting for 'ENTER'. It was started by Python script, and it is connected to terminal.

Comment: You need to run the program using a pipe, preferably using `subprocess.Popen`.  Just send it a `'\n'`.  Or are you asking for a process that is currently running?

Comment: also check out `pexpect`.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do such thing but with proc name using Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) but not with PID.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['proc_name', filePath], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)
p.stdin.print('\n') # sends Enter into process
```

Comment: filePath reffers to which file?!

Comment: subprocess stdin doesn't have print(). Also, by default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence, you can't use process name but executable path